# How to parse Date to DateTime in the own datagrid in Xaml

Tags: xaml, date, parsing, datetime, grid

I have a little problem. My codebehind is returning a correctly datetime but when I show it in my grid (using devexpress) it isn't showing the time, just date. My code is:

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="{lex:Loc col_HoraEntrada}" FieldName="HORA_CUADRANTE_ENTRADA" AutoFilterCondition="Contains"
```

My dateTime format 2015-11-17 13:30:00.000
And I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most of the cases when one data type should be converter to another data type just for presentation - you should use [ValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is very easy example of ValueConverter: [WPF Tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

Just notice that ValueConverter instance should be defined as Resource. That's it: you should define it as entity that has `x:Key` parameter somewhere and then use it in you `Binding`